# Doubt about subspaces being vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Whenever i am saying $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space, it means it has $n$ basis vectors each with n elements, right.

So when i am proving some theorems or relations involving some $m$-dimensional subspaces of $V$, am i assuming that there will be only m elements in the original bases of $V$ and the rest of $n-m$ elements will be $0$, because i dont think m dimensional vector space will have n elements in its bases.

If I am wrong, please explain with an example.

I do have a confusing example in my mind:

$A=[1,0,1]$ and $B=[0,1,0]$; both are linearly independent, can they act as bases for some vector space $L=\operatorname{span}(A \cup B)$.

Comment: The bases of the vector space and one of its subspaces can be disjoint.  Consider the Euclidean plane and a line through the origin which is not parallel to one of the axes.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the definition of a subspace many places, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition_and_useful_characterization_of_subspace) suffices. Consider the case $n=2$, $m=1$ with $V=\mathbb R^2$ and $W=\{(x,0)|x\in\mathbb R\}$. Then $W$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace of the $2$-dimensional space $V$. A basis of $V$ is $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and a basis for $W$ is $\{(1,0)\}$.

Comment: what about the edit?

Comment: It is basically the same thing, just rotated and embedded in $\mathbb R^3$. Since $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent, they span a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R ^3$. Basically, $A$ plays the role of $(1,0)$ and $B$ plays the role of $(0,1)$ in my example.